# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'match' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, windows, email, ubuntu, beautifulsoup

I have gone through all the related issue stackoverflow,github issues, etc.,

I am running into issue when executing below function. As per solutions, I have tried creating global variable and python version changes and checked all possible ways. But I am running into this issue while running from ubuntu. The code is working fine from windows.

```
def extract_info(email_message):
    for payload in email_message.get_payload():
        html_mail = payload.get_payload()
    BS = BSHTML(html_mail)
    val = BS.find_all('tr')
    return val
```

## calling the function using

data = extract_info(email_message1)

Error:
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/correct_version/lib/python3.6/_markupbase.py", line 160, in parse_marked_section
    if not match:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'match' referenced before assignment

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from the lines of code we can see. Where is the code that references _match_ ?

Comment: I've experienced the same error. Its source is the core HTMLParser library.
After digging around, I found that there's an open issue:
https://bugs.python.org/issue34480 .
Maybe changing the specified parser would help: `BS = BSHTML(html_mail, "lxml")`. I have not tried this myself yet as I'm only able to replicate the error on a certain remote environment which I cannot easily alter.

Comment: Indeed, but doesn't seem solved yet